# iteration 500 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]

Tags: arduino

I am working on an Arduino code and the code seems to be good and well structured but i have an error in one line of I think or maybe I forgot to add smthg anyway here is the code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
const int dsize = 500;
int analogPin = A0;    
int data[dsize];
int counter = 0;
unsigned long measurmentDelay = 600000; //10 min

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX

unsigned long time_now = millis();

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
delay(500);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.println("###Power on###");
  int i=0;
  for (i = 0; i < dsize+1; i = i+1) {
    data[i]=0;
  }
  time_now = millis();
}
```

and I have this error and I don't know what to do

```
H:\Python\sketch_feb19a\sketch_feb19a.ino: In function 'setup':

H:\Python\sketch_feb19a\sketch_feb19a.ino:20:14: warning: iteration 500 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]

     data[i]=0;

              ^

H:\Python\sketch_feb19a\sketch_feb19a.ino:19:3: note: containing loop

   for (i = 0; i < dsize+1; i = i+1) {

   ^
```

Please if anyone can help I would be thankful.

Comment: For future reference, please read on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As a matter of fact, had you done so, you would have seen the error: you declared an array of 500 positions and attempted to access `data[500]`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the error is pretty clear. It tells you that in your loop the iteration 500 has something wrong on it.

If you take a closer look, you will see that `data` is a 500 element array.

You are iterating from 0 to 500 (both included) so it's 501 elements.

To solve it, your loop should only have 500 steps, not 501 (basically remove the +1 in the code)

```
for (i = 0; i < dsize; i = i+1)
```